# acceptance of answer doesn't give points

Tags: support

not so important, but an answer I gave was accepted today on StackOverflow.com without giving reputation points. I got a badge, but that's all I saw. Is it something I am missing or is it a bug?

Comment: Could you give a link to it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm assuming you're talking about [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18559600/facebook-app-check-user-permissions/18559712#18559712). You didn't receive reputation for the acceptance because you have it marked as a Community Wiki answer, and you don't get reputation from those.

Answer (score 5):

Was it [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18562672/254830)? You appear to have correctly received reputation for it on [your SO account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2059741/tattvamasi):

[image: Tattvamasi's reputation page, showing 15 points for an accepted answer]